# Python logging.DEBUG level doesn't logging

Tags: python, logging, syslog-ng

I have a problem with python's `logging` lib. With the code below I create a "logger":

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
def logger_init(level):
    try:
        syslog = SysLogHandler(address=LOG_DESTINATION)
    except Exception, ex:
        return
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(module)s[%(process)d]: %(message)s')
    syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
    syslog.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(syslog)
```

And I call it like:

> logger.debug(SOME_STR_TO_BE_LOGGED)

OR like:

> logger.error(SOME_STR_TO_BE_LOGGED)

And I initialize the logger with:

```
log_level = logging.ERROR
if options.DEBUG_LOG: ####  This comes from options parser and it is True.
    log_level = logging.DEBUG
logger_init(log_level)
```

The problem is that the `error`, and `warn` is working very well, but neither `info` nor `debug` methods prints anything to syslog.

I'm using syslog-ng and I designed my filter, that is it will accept every level from `debug` to `emerg`.

What is the problem here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You also have to set the level of the logger, not only the handler.

Add this to your `logger_init`:

```
logger.setLevel(level)
```

Comment: spent some time scratching my head about this.. thanks a lot for helping catch it.